# Save textfile to appdata and then load from file

Tags: vb.net, text-files

Ok what i am trying to do is this: I want to save data to a textfile that will be saved in appdata, i will be packaging up the application so the user will be installing it.

To write a text file here's my code:

```
 Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("test.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        file.Close()
```

This will save the file to the directory the app is run from, from what i see when i debug. But it to save to app data when the app is installed and ran, heres the code to save in app data:

```
Dim appDataPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

How do i make my textfile save to the string `appdatapath`? Im assuming i could only see the change if i try to package the app and install it myself? since it's debugging Visual studio wont actually make a folder in appdata for it right? But i want to be able to specify that location as the save location. Thanks. Using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: `FullFileName = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "text.text")`

Comment: where would that line of code go? im not a vb expert don't just paste code, thank you

Comment: @UriahsVictor
`dim FullFileName as String = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "text.text")`
and then
`file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(FullFileName, True)`